# how to do unit testing for this type of code in windows form c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, unit-testing

```
public int validation()
{
    int flag = 0;
    Regex Rx = new Regex(@"^[\p{L} \.'\-]{0,20}$");
    Regex Rx1 = new Regex(@"^[\p{L} \.'\-]{0,20}$");
    Regex Rx2 = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{10}$");
    if (name.Text=="")
    {
        name.Focus();
        errorProvider1.SetError(name, MessageBox.Show("enter your name", 
            "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
        flag = 1;
    }
    else if (fathername.Text == "")
    {
        fathername.Focus();
        errorProvider1.SetError(name, MessageBox.Show("Enter your father name", 
            "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

**its public validation part code for windows form**

Comment: 1. `errorProvider1.SetError(name, MessageBox?!)`?  2. What's role of those `Regex`? 3. Please post [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

To write effective unit tests, first your code should be *testable*. To have a testable piece of code first you should separate the business from UI. In this way you can test your business via unit testing. Also if you use MVVM patterns you can test your UI logic independently from your UI technology.

Answer (score 0):

The common of unit testing steps is.
Arrange -> Act -> Assert 
In my opinion, I should write your code in separate method to validate. The method will return true or false. It's easy to check and unit testing. 
regards.

```
public bool ValidateInput(string input)
{
  Regex Rx = new Regex(@"^[\p{L} \.'\-]{0,20}$");
  Match match = rx.Match(input);
  if(match.Success) return true;
  return false;
}
// To call the method.
public void Testing(){
  string userName = "your user name";
  if(ValidateInput(userName))
    MessageBox.Show("Your username incorrect.");
  else{
    // Todo something.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code ..but i'm getting error in Regex part..even i added assembly reference of the form code